# integer object property inside another object also with integer properties

Tags: javascript

Neewbie Javascript question!!

How does one access a property of an object named with an integer that is within another object that also uses properties named with integers.

Ex.

```
var obj={1:{2:3}};
```

I can do this -

```
var innrObj=obj[1];

var value = innrObj[2];

// 3
```

But is there one line of code to achieve the same?

Comment: That they're integer keys is not relevant. (In fact they'll be converted to strings anyway.)

Answer (score 1):

You can just call them together

```js
var obj = {
  1: {
    2: 3
  }
};
var value = obj[1][2];

snippet.log('value: ' + value)
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

the fact that the keys are irrelevant, if the property key is a [valid identifier](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Identifier) name then you can use [dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Dot_notation) to access it otherwise you can use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation)(it can be used in all cases)

Comment: +1. And the fact that the properties are integers is irrelevant. This syntax works for any nested objects with any properties.

Comment: Thanks. I thought I had tried that. Sorry. Should have researched further.